# Insert into Azure SQL database from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to insert data into Azure SQL Database using NodeJS interface.

```
sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();
    // query to the database and get the records
    var q = "INSERT INTO md.GameMaster(gameCode,gtype,config,gprovider,launchdate,isdeleted) VALUES('"+gcode+"','"+gtype+"','"+config+"','"+gprovider+"','"+launchdate+"','N')"
    console.log(q)
    request.query(q, function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
    });
});
```

This is the code that I have for running the insert query on Azure SQL database.

It is giving the error

```
TypeError: The "config.server" property is required and must be of type string.
at new Connection (D:\masterdata\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:89:13)
at shared.Promise (D:\masterdata\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:61:23)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at ConnectionPool._poolCreate (D:\masterdata\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:12:12)
at ConnectionPool._connect (D:\masterdata\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\connection-pool.js:166:10)
at ConnectionPool.connect (D:\masterdata\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\connection-pool.js:136:12)
at Object.connect (D:\masterdata\node_modules\mssql\lib\global-connection.js:57:29)
at app.post (D:\masterdata\app.js:64:5)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\masterdata\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (D:\masterdata\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
INSERT INTO md.GameMaster(gameCode,gtype,config,gprovider,launchdate,isdeleted) VALUES('ATG','Slot','some 5  some 3','Playtech','2019-12-20','N')
{ ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
at Request._query (D:\masterdata\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:447:37)
at Request._query (D:\masterdata\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\request.js:346:11)
at Request.query (D:\masterdata\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\request.js:383:12)
at D:\masterdata\app.js:71:13
at _poolCreate.then.catch.err (D:\masterdata\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\connection-pool.js:241:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7) code: 'ECONNCLOSED', name: 'ConnectionError' }
```

I am not sure why is it happening. When I run a select query instead of insert it works.

Comment: Your `config` object does not include `server` property or the property is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this node.js code, I tested select query and insert, it all works ok:

```
const { Connection, Request } = require("tedious");

// Create connection to database
const config = {
  authentication: {
    options: {
      userName: "ServerAdmin", // update me
      password: "****" // update me
    },
    type: "default"
  },
  server: "sqlserver.database.windows.net", // update me
  options: {
    database: "Mydatabase", //update me
    encrypt: true
  }
};

const connection = new Connection(config);

// Attempt to connect and execute queries if connection goes through
connection.on("connect", err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  } else {
    queryDatabase();
  }
});

function queryDatabase() {
  console.log("Reading rows from the Table...");

  // Read all rows from table

    //SQL satement
    var id = 3
    var value ='444444'
    var sql = "insert test3(id,sql) values ("+id+",'"+value+"')"
    console.log('query========='+sql)

  const request = new Request(sql,
    (err, rowCount)=> {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      } else {
        console.log('rowCount======='+rowCount);
      }
    }
  );


  connection.execSql(request);
}
```

Reference: [Quickstart: Use Node.js to query an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-nodejs#get-sql-server-connection-information).

Hope this helps.

Comment: what worked for me was adding a connection.connect() after the connection was created from config, otherwise connection.on('connect', ...) was not triggered at all.

Comment: Thanks Akkonrad, that fixed my issue.